# Nodejs - prevent socket.io from dropping the frame rates

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, animation, html5-canvas

I'm trying to program some animations in html5 canvas. I need the animations to be reproduced on any other client connected to my server. So what I do is I send the function to be called and the arguments as a string and call eval() on the client side. That way the animation logic needs to be done only on one canvas, while the function calls that actually render things are executed by all clients.

However, my frame rates drop drastically when I do this. I use socket.emit() to send signals to the server which in turn calls socket.broadcast.emit() to send the string to all clients. This is the rendering loop :

```
var rf = function()
{
   // clear background
   context.fillStyle = "#000";
   context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
   socket.emit('action', 'clearScreen', "{}");
   // mouse position to head towards
   var cx = (mousex - width / 2) + (width / 2),
       cy = (mousey - height / 2) + (height / 2);

   // update all stars
   var sat = Floor(Z * 500);       // Z range 0.01 -> 0.5
   if (sat > 100) sat = 100;
   for (var i=0; i<units; i++)
   {
      var n = stars[i],            // the star
          xx = n.x / n.z,          // star position
          yy = n.y / n.z,
          e = (1.0 / n.z + 1) * 2;   // size i.e. z

      if (n.px !== 0)
      {
         // hsl colour from a sine wave
         context.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + ((cycle * i) % 360) + "," + sat + "%,80%)";
         context.lineWidth = e;
         context.beginPath();
         socket.emit('action', 'context.beginPath', "{}");
         context.moveTo(xx + cx, yy + cy);
         socket.emit('action', 'context.moveTo', "{\"a\": [" + (xx + cx) + "," + (yy + cy) + "]}");
         context.lineTo(n.px + cx, n.py + cy);
         socket.emit('action', 'context.lineTo', "{\"a\": [" + (n.px + cx) + "," + (n.py + cy) + "]}");
         context.stroke();
         socket.emit('action', 'context.stroke', "{}");
      }

      // update star position values with new settings
      n.px = xx;
      n.py = yy;
      n.z -= Z;

      // reset when star is out of the view field
      if (n.z < Z || n.px > width || n.py > height)
      {
         // reset star
         resetstar(n);
      }
   }

   // colour cycle sinewave rotation
   cycle += 0.01;

   requestAnimFrame(rf);
};
requestAnimFrame(rf);
```

The above snippet was taken from [here](http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/warpfield/).

Can you suggest ways to prevent the frame rates from dropping? I guess this can be done if socket.emit was non-blocking. 
Sending strings that reproduces the frame is the lightest way to accomplish what i want. Sending pixels are even more heavy. Sending strings works fine when the frame is easy to draw - for example a simple circle moving up and down renders fine.

Comment: Have you tried using a single `emit` signal to send all the data?

Comment: No. But would that help? I will try that. Its true that 4 emits will be reduced to 1. But it would still bring the fps down right? Is there a way to make the call non-blocking?

Comment: Calls are non-blocking in the first place. It just means that you can make another call without waiting for the result of that one. You increase the overhead of transfer by making multiple `emit` signals, that's all. And it takes longer to arrive to the destination. So if you send it as just one `emit`, it will all arrive at the same time.

Comment: Send a JSON object instead of raw data, see if it helps.

Comment: Will do that and report back :)

Comment: Theoretically multiple calls should not bring down the fps in the page that is rendering the original code. If the calls are indeed non-blocking, the data should be sent and the code continues executing. It is the client side that should be feeling the lag (and it is lagging). But the FPS of the original canvas coming down is what I don't understand.

Comment: Well, it depends on the number of threads that Node is using to "simulate" non-blocking calls. If this number gets too high, the `emit` calls stack up and wait for its turn for some CPU time. As much as Node and other multithread applications advertise, if you use too many "asynchronous" calls, they will get in line behind each other eventually. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been down the road you're traveling now. It's an interesting & fun road, but sometimes a frustrating road. *Have fun and be patient!*

OK...here are a few hints:

1. **All your drawing commands must be atomic.** Each command sent to any client must define a complete drawing operation (a complete path operation from beginPath through stroke).
2. **Make your clients smart.** Give each client at least enough javascript smarts to draw each primitive shape after being given a primitive definition. Client side functions: drawLine(), drawRect(), drawCircle(), drawBCurve(), drawQCurve(), drawText(), etc.
3. **Emits can be lost**. This is why it's not a good idea to just send raw context commands.  Include a serial index# in each command object and, after processing each command array, append that new array to a master array (the master array contains all arrays ever received). This way the client can recognize and request replacements of missing packets. Hint: you can even use this master array to replay the entire animation ;-)

Here are some example snippets which expand my hints (not complete or tested!):

**On the computer issuing the drawing commands**

```
// emits can be lost
// include an index# with each command so clients
// can request replacements for lost commands
var nextCommand=1;

// an array to hold all commands to be sent with the next emit
var commands=[];

// Example: push 1 atomic line command into the commands array
commands.push({
        op:'line',
        x0:xx+cx,
        y0:yy+cy,
        x1:n.px+cx,
        y1:n.py+cy,
        stroke:"hsl("+((cycle*i)%360)+","+sat+"%,80%)",
        fill:null,
        index:(nextCommand++),   
});

// Continue adding commands to be sent in this emit
// Push any more atomic drawing commands into commands[]
// You will probably generate many commands through a loop

// serialize the commands array and emit it
socket.emit(JSON.stringify(commands));
```

**On each client**

```
// context color changes are expensive
// Don't change the color if the context is already that color
// These vars hold the current context color for comparison
var currentStroke='';
var currentFill='';

// deserialize the incoming commands back into an array of JS command objects
var commands=JSON.parse(receivedCommands);

// process each command in the array
for(var i=0;i<commands.length;i++){

    var cmd=commands[i];

    // execute each command's atomic drawing based on op-type
    switch(cmd.op){
        case 'line':
            drawLine(cmd);
            break;
        // ... also 'circle','rect',etc.
    }

}

// draw a line defined by an atomic line drawing command
function drawLine(cmd){

    if(stroke){

        // execute primitive line commands
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(cmd.x0,cmd.y0);
        context.lineTo(cmd.x1,cmd.y1);

        // Don't change the color if the context is already that color
        if(stroke!==currentStroke){
            context.strokeStyle=stroke;
            currentStroke=stroke;
        }

        // stroke the line (this completes an atomic line draw--beginPath thru stroke)
        context.stroke();
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have you done a similar project? Is it open source? Writing custom functions like drawLine() is one thing i wanted to avoid. If i keep it down to existing HTML commands, i can one day write a script to convert ANY HTML canvas example to be compatible with my program.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, I was the lead on a similar project that allowed quality control engineers to collaborate while marking up product issues. The app is proprietary. About drawing functions like drawLine() on the client: These functions represent the minimal drawing commands necessary to successfully accomplish rendering a shape to the canvas. Even if you send individual commands from your server, you must still issue this same set of commands (beginPath,moveTo,lineTo,stroke). I've found having a mildly smarter client reduces many problems introduced by remoting. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I was calling the socket.emit from a loop and in my herculean efforts to make signal emits more efficient, I overlooked this silly fact. As you suggested I pushed all my commands into an array and sent the array and FPS seems to be up.

Answer (score 0):

Emit only **once** per frame, sending an object `actions` containing all the informations

```
var rf = function()
{
   var actions = {};//prepare the object to be sent
   // clear background
   context.fillStyle = "#000";
   context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
   //socket.emit('action', 'clearScreen', "{}");
   actions['clearScreen'] = "{}";
   // mouse position to head towards
   var cx = (mousex - width / 2) + (width / 2),
       cy = (mousey - height / 2) + (height / 2);

   // update all stars
   var sat = Floor(Z * 500);       // Z range 0.01 -> 0.5
   if (sat > 100) sat = 100;
   actions['stars'] = [];//push all the star related actions in this array
   for (var i=0; i<units; i++)
   {
      var n = stars[i],            // the star
          xx = n.x / n.z,          // star position
          yy = n.y / n.z,
          e = (1.0 / n.z + 1) * 2;   // size i.e. z

      if (n.px !== 0)
      {
         // hsl colour from a sine wave
         context.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + ((cycle * i) % 360) + "," + sat + "%,80%)";
         context.lineWidth = e;
         context.beginPath();
         //socket.emit('action', 'context.beginPath', "{}");
         actions['stars'].push({
            'context.beginPath' : "{}"
         });
         context.moveTo(xx + cx, yy + cy);
         //socket.emit('action', 'context.moveTo', "{\"a\": [" + (xx + cx) + "," + (yy + cy) + "]}");
         actions['stars'].push({
            'context.moveTo' : "{\"a\": [" + (xx + cx) + "," + (yy + cy) + "]}"
         });
         context.lineTo(n.px + cx, n.py + cy);
         //socket.emit('action', 'context.lineTo', "{\"a\": [" + (n.px + cx) + "," + (n.py + cy) + "]}");
         actions['stars'].push({
            'context.lineTo' : "{\"a\": [" + (n.px + cx) + "," + (n.py + cy) + "]}"
         });
         context.stroke();
         //socket.emit('action', 'context.stroke', "{}");
         actions['stars'].push({
            'context.stroke' : "{}"
         });
      }

      // update star position values with new settings
      n.px = xx;
      n.py = yy;
      n.z -= Z;

      // reset when star is out of the view field
      if (n.z < Z || n.px > width || n.py > height)
      {
         // reset star
         resetstar(n);
      }
   }

   // colour cycle sinewave rotation
   cycle += 0.01;

   //emit only once
   socket.emit('actions',actions);

   requestAnimFrame(rf);
};
//requestAnimFrame(rf);
rf();//call directly
```